# anything more accurate than Marshal.SizeOf?

Tags: c#, char, sizeof

The size of a `char` is 2 bytes in c# but `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(char))` equals 1:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(char)));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

output: 1

Is there any methods anything more accurate than Marshal.SizeOf in .Net?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2013/06/13/whats-the-difference-sizeof-and-marshal-sizeof/. Basically a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49459806/difference-between-marshal-sizeof-and-sizeof-i-just-dont-get-it.

Comment: @EugenePodskal But i'm not asking for why. I want a method that gives the size of a type.

Comment: Well, ok, agree that the duplicate is not exactly a duplicate (though it contains the answer), on the other hand the premise of the question is also not exactly correct (SizeOf is 100% correct for what it should do). In such a case the answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/8175490/3745022